# Maish's T&L Deli

Tags: name-significance, stuart-kaminsky, abe-lieberman

I'm reading a series of books by [Stuart Kaminsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuart_M._Kaminsky) (highly recommended) about a Jewish Chicago cop/detective named Abe Lieberman.

One of the frequent scenes in the series is the deli run by his brother Morris (Maish): *Maish's T&L Deli*. I haven't been able to figure (or remember) the source of the name. What does T&L represent? The L could possibly be Lieberman and the deli has had several incarnations owned within the family and it has moved around Chicago over the years. But T&L might also be a reference to something in Yiddish, terms of which frequently appear.

Any help with the meaning of the name of the deli is appreciated.